# k8s frontend app can't reach the k8s backend app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have this setup with a frontend express app and a backend mongodb app represented by the image below. Here I have a k8s cluster with one master and two worker nodes. The private worker node is int private subnet along with the master node, while the public worker node is in the public subnet. The private subnet accesses the internet via a AWS NAT Gateway, and the public subnet via an Internet Gateway.

[image]

The the backend app runs successfully, but the front end fails with the following error:

```
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------


(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://mongousername:undefined@mongodb-service:27017/"
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb-service:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongodb-service
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It can reach the address of the backend. This is the backend and frontend configs:

frontend:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 name: mongodb-configmap
data:
 database_url: mongodb-service

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: mongo-express
 labels:
   app: mongo-express
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: mongo-express
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: mongo-express
   spec:
     affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - frontend
     containers:
     - name: mongo-express
       image: mongo-express
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8081
       env:
       - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
         valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:
             name: mongodb-secret
             key: mongodb-root-username
       - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWOR
         valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:
             name: mongodb-secret
             key: mongodb-root-password
       - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
         valueFrom:
           configMapKeyRef:
             name: mongodb-configmap
             key: database_url
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mongo-express-service
spec:
 selector:
   app: mongo-express
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 8081
     targetPort: 8081
     nodePort: 30000
```

backend:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
 mongodb-root-username: bW9uZ291c2VybmFtZQ==
 mongodb-root-password: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==

---

apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment # mongodb deployment
metadata:
 name: mongodb-deployment
 labels:
   app: mongodb
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: mongodb
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: mongodb
   spec: # mongodb deployment spec
     affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - backend
     containers:
       - name: mongodb-container
         image: mongo # mongo image name
         ports: # mongodb container ports
         - containerPort: 27017
         env: # mongodb container env variables
         - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
           valueFrom: # mongodb env variable value from secret
             secretKeyRef:
               name: mongodb-secret
               key: mongodb-root-username
         - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
           valueFrom: # mongodb ev variable from secret
             secretKeyRef:
               name: mongodb-secret
               key: mongodb-root-password

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mongodb-service
 annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
 selector:
   app: mongodb
 ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 27017
     targetPort: 27017
```

Updates:

from `kubectl get svc`:

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE

kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP     3d7h
mongodb-service   ClusterIP   10.100.40.68   <none>        27017/TCP   2d15h
```

from `kubect describe service mongodb-service`:

```
Name:              mongodb-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-internal: true
Selector:          app=mongodb
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.100.40.68
IPs:               10.100.40.68
Port:              <unset>  27017/TCP
TargetPort:        27017/TCP
Endpoints:         10.44.0.1:27017
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: what does kubectl get svc show?

Comment: `NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP     3d7h
mongodb-service   ClusterIP   10.100.40.68   <none>        27017/TCP   2d15h` this is what I get @richardrublev

Comment: kubectl describe service mongodb-service.

Comment: `Name:              mongodb-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-internal: true
Selector:          app=mongodb
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.100.40.68
IPs:               10.100.40.68
Port:              <unset>  27017/TCP
TargetPort:        27017/TCP
Endpoints:         10.44.0.1:27017
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>` @richardrublev output from the describe command

Comment: kubectl port-forward svc/mongodb-service 27017:27017

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-10-0-128-33:~$ kubectl port-forward svc/mongodb-service 27017:27017
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:27017 -> 27017
Forwarding from [::1]:27017 -> 27017` @richardrublev update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254519/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-richard-rublev).